# What am I misunderstanding in my boolean radio group in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, formik, radio-group

Following the [Radio Group Example](https://formik.org/docs/examples/radio-group) in the Formik docs and using Bootstrap 5 I've tried to create a boolean radio component that gets passed in a `name` and `label`. However, on render with the `initialValues`:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    foo: false,
    bar: false,
  }}>
```

the `no` is selected because the initial value is set to false but whenever `yes` is chosen the radio will not fill in, component:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Field } from 'formik'

const RadioBool = ({ name, label }) => {
  const yesId = `${name}-yes`
  const noId = `${name}-no`
  return (
    <>
      <p id={`${name}-group-label`}>{label}:</p>
      <div className="form-group mb-4" role="group" aria-labelledby={`${name}-group-label`}>
        <div className="form-check">
          <label htmlFor={yesId}>Yes</label>
          <Field id={yesId} className="form-check-input" type="radio" name={name} value={true} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-check">
          <label htmlFor={noId}>No</label>
          <Field id={noId} className="form-check-input" type="radio" name={name} value={false} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

RadioBool.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default RadioBool
```

but if `checked` is added to `Yes`, example:

```
<Field id={yesId} className="form-check-input" type="radio" name={name} value={true} checked />
```

the radio group works and I'm not sure why.

tests:

```
<RadioBool name="foo" label="Look at foo?" />
<RadioBool name="bar" label="Look at bar?" />
```

### Research

- [How to add Radio Button in Formik Validations Reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065376/how-to-add-radio-button-in-formik-validations-reactjs)
- [How to create Radio buttons with Formik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658020/how-to-create-radio-buttons-with-formik)
- [How to make use of Radio Group with useFormik Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171436/how-to-make-use-of-radio-group-with-useformik-hook)
- [how do you use onChange property on react formik radio field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67858694/how-do-you-use-onchange-property-on-react-formik-radio-field)
- [formik radio button validation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531029/formik-radio-button-validation-issues)

Why does my boolean radio component not work in Formik unless `checked` is used on one `<Field />`?

Comment: try removing `value` from field. In the example you mentioned, the `value` is used as string not true or false. Use `checked` property for initial value https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-heisenberg-kteomb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is described here [Radio values must be strings, can't be numbers or booleans](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/2044) and as I see it's not solved 'from the box' yet.

In my `TypeScript` project I've created custom component. May it would be helpfull for you:

```
  import React, { FC } from 'react';

  type Props = {
    name: string
    value: boolean
    checked: boolean
    setValues: (values: React.SetStateAction<any>, shouldValidate?: boolean) => void;
  }
  
  const RadioButtonBooleanField: FC<Props> = ({name, value, checked, setValues}) => {
    return (
      <input type='radio' className="form-check-input" name={name} value={String(value)} checked={checked}
        onChange={(e: any) => {
          setValues((prevValues: any) => ({
            ...prevValues,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value === "true"
            }))
          }
        } 
      />
    );
  };
```

It can be used like this inside `Formik` component:

```
{({ errors, touched, values, setValues }) => (
   <RadioButtonBooleanField name="IsExtendedView" value={false} checked={!values.IsExtendedView} setValues={setValues}/>
)}
```